# Plot a 3D function from a datafile (csv or excel file) using Gnuplot

Tags: csv, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot a 3D graph using a data file with three columns, one for the X-axis, one for the Y-axis, and the other for the Z-axis. Here's a sample of my file:

```
0,614,0.0
1,614,0.09340286
2,614,0.09353256
3,614,0.09371185
4,614,0.09384537
5,614,0.09400177
6,614,0.09416962
...
419,614,0.13825226
420,614,0.13843536
0,613,48.794716
1,613,0.09355545
2,613,0.093696594
```

I've got 420 x values and 594 y values (x range : [0:420] ; y range : [20:614])
If you have any ideas to plot this file with gnuplot, or with any other software (Excel 2016 / Libreoffice 6.0 etc.) Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Ahem. That's a really easy job with all the software mentioned. Check e.g. the demo section on the gnuplot homepage, and check for `datafile separator` and `splot` in the gp help. RTFM ;-) And with excel, it's even simpler really, though excel graphs are notoriously ugly.

Comment: The thing with Excel is that it does not interpret my data columns properly, and I saw that I had to change it. I found [this](https://youtu.be/28MYjylKvwI) paid software to do the job, but yes I agree with you, excel graphs don't look very good.
But I managed to get my graph with gnuplot, by deleting all the ',' in the csv file, and with the help of this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/716014/create-a-smooth-surface-using-x-y-z-data-gnuplot).
But even if I use set 'datafile separator ',' ' I can't get it to work. But anyway it's working now thanks.